# BCrypt error Illegal arguments: undefined, string

Tags: javascript, node.js, registration, bcrypt, http-status-code-204

I tried to register a user but everytime I did it I get this error:

```
C:\Users\reut\Desktop\Final-Project-2-main\server\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:189
            throw Error("Illegal arguments: "+(typeof s)+', '+(typeof salt));
                  ^

Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at Object.bcrypt.hashSync (C:\Users\reut\Desktop\Final-Project-2-main\server\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:189:19)
    at generateHashPassword (C:\Users\reut\Desktop\Final-Project-2-main\server\services\bcrypt.js:4:17)     
    at C:\Users\reut\Desktop\Final-Project-2-main\server\Routers\Users\userRouter.js:29:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

My code:

userRouter:

```
const validateRegistration = require("./usersValidations/registraion");
const validateSignin = require("./usersValidations/SignUp");
const {
  comparePassword,
  generateHashPassword,
} = require("../../services/bcrypt");
const { generateAuthToken } = require("../../services/token");
const _ = require("lodash");
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("./userModel");
const auth = require("../../middlewares/authorization");
const chalk = require("chalk");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateRegistration(req.body);
  if (error) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright(error.details[0].message));
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  }

  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (user) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright("Registration Error: User already registered"));
    return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");
  }

  user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ["name", "email", "password", "biz"]));

  user.password = generateHashPassword(user.password);
  await user.save();
  res.send(_.pick(user, ["_id", "name", "email"]));
});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateSignin(req.body);
  if (error) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright(error.details[0].message));
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  }

  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (!user) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright("Invalid email"));
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password.");
  }

  const validPassword = comparePassword(req.body.password, user.password);
  if (!validPassword) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright("Invalid password"));
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password.");
  }

  res.json({
    token: generateAuthToken(user),
  });
});

router.get("/userinfo", auth, (req, res) => {
  let user = req.user;

  User.findById(user._id)
    .select(["-password", "-createdAt", "-__v"])
    .then((user) => res.send(user))
    .catch((errorsFromMongoose) => res.status(500).send(errorsFromMongoose));
});

module.exports = router;
```

bcrypt.js

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

function generateHashPassword(pass) {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(pass, 10);
}

function comparePassword(password, anotherPassword) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, anotherPassword);
}

module.exports = { generateHashPassword, comparePassword };
```

And I can't to connect with user have already.
I will glad to know why I have problem.
Thank You!
And if something missing in the post please let me know and don't vote againt my post I juat need help and I don't want StackOverFlow will block me.